# How can i edit list of class object id property in my controller class action method by loop through list object to match id obtain from another view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
    // This is my controller class containing to action method 

    // this is list of student type
    List<Student> std = new List<Student>();
            // here i add item in list and pass it to my index.cshtml
            public ActaionResult Index()
            {
                std.Add(new Student {Id = 1,Name = "Nazir",Roll = "13b-049-bs",Batch = "13b" });
                std.Add(new Student {Id = 2 ,Name = "Hamza", Roll = "13b-034-bs", Batch = "13b" });
                return View(std);
            }

    // this is my edit action method invoke when user click on edit to 
//corresponding record make request like Student/Edit/1

            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Edit(int id) 
            {
                Student student = null;
                foreach(Student item in std){
    // here i compare the id coming from url request to list of student type
                    if (item.Id == id) {
                        student = item;
                    }
                }
                return View(student);
            }

    // this is my edit.cshtml file

    @model Test.Models.Student

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    }

    <h2>Edit</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Student</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

            <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
   // In here display Name of student object property 
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Roll, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
  // In here display Roll of student object property 
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Roll, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Roll, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Batch, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
        // In here display Batch of student object property 
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Batch, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Batch, "", new { 
        @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  }
```

but data doesn't appear in html controls

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an object std in two different request contexts. You need to have some state mechanism like Session ,TempData ,Application etc to store information you wanted to later access.

For your example right way is to extract object creation outside of action and call it from another action would do it.

```
// this is list of student type
List<Student> std = new List<Student>();

public void GetStudents() {
 std.Add(new Student {
  Id = 1, Name = "Nazir", Roll = "13b-049-bs", Batch = "13b"
 });
 std.Add(new Student {
  Id = 2, Name = "Hamza", Roll = "13b-034-bs", Batch = "13b"
 });
}

// here i add item in list and pass it to my index.cshtml
public ActaionResult Index() {
 var std = GetStudents();
 return View(std);
}
// this is my edit action method invoke when user click on edit to
```

//corresponding record make request like Student/Edit/1

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id) 
        {
            GetStudents(); // notice call here...
            Student student = null;
            foreach(Student item in std){
// here i compare the id coming from url request to list of student type
                if (item.Id == id) {
                    student = item;
                }
            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

and if you want to use State , Stored GetStudents Data in Session/Tempdata and then use that directly without calling GetStudents in Edit Method

I hope that helps !!